# Racket: Issue with Sorting Strings in Ascending Order

Tags: sorting, scheme, racket

I've written a Scheme function to sort strings in ascending order. Here's my code:

```lisp
(define (sort-word word)
  (list->string (sort (string->list word) char<?)))

(display (sort-word "Hello"))
```

I expect this to sort the word "Hello" in lexicographically ascending order but it outputs "Hello". However, if I enter "cba" for my input, I get "abc as output. Where could the issue in my code be, and how can I achieve the desired behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: what is `(char<? #\H #\e)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, now at least I know where the problem is. However, the upper and lower case must be retained and I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Select `char<?` in DrRacket, right-click/control-click for a menu, choose "Search in help desk for...": find the `<` variant needed.

Comment: Use `#:key char-downcase`. (see explanation of key in the docs for sort.